# Create Drawable from Android Vector Asset XML on Runtime

Tags: android, firebase, android-vectordrawable

I have stored all my vector asset xml files in firebase storage. Now, I want to download them and add each file to an `ImageButton`. But for that, I have to convert the xml file to a drawable but neither `Drawable.createFromXml()` or `Drawable.createFromPath()` works.

The problem I have when using `Drawable.createFromXml()` is that I don't know what parser I should enter.

Is it possible to create a drawable from an xml file (svg file) at runtime or does any one of you know a better approach to this.

This is the code at the moment:

```
    private void getData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    HashMap<String,Drawable> testMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        testMap.put(ds.getKey().toString(), Drawable.createFromPath(generateXmlFile(ds.getValue().toString())));
    }
}

private String generateXmlFile(String downloadXml){
    StorageReference xmlFile = storageInstance.getReferenceFromUrl(downloadXml);
    try {
        File tmpFile = File.createTempFile( "test","xml");
        xmlFile.getFile(tmpFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            }
        });
        return tmpFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```